# How can I plot OpenStreetMap by road (or way) instead of by geolocation?

Tags: python, openstreetmap, osmnx

A sample of my data:

```
        longitude   latitude    count
way_id          
3996189 -3.732425   40.362795   12173
3996191 -3.596423   40.429618   1656
3996195 -3.603010   40.429786   211
3996196 -3.605451   40.434605   772
3996199 -3.606216   40.434230   1063
3996203 -3.606369   40.434044   40
3997425 -3.606917   40.424344   3080
3997426 -3.607961   40.434094   2095
3997427 -3.604154   40.423951   465
3997428 -3.606116   40.425008   217
```

To replicate this DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'longitude': {3996189: -3.732425,
  3996191: -3.596423,
  3996195: -3.60301,
  3996196: -3.605451,
  3996199: -3.606216,
  3996203: -3.606369,
  3997425: -3.606917,
  3997426: -3.607961,
  3997427: -3.604154,
  3997428: -3.606116},
 'latitude': {3996189: 40.362795,
  3996191: 40.429618,
  3996195: 40.429786,
  3996196: 40.434605,
  3996199: 40.43423,
  3996203: 40.434044,
  3997425: 40.424344,
  3997426: 40.434094,
  3997427: 40.423951,
  3997428: 40.425008},
 'count': {3996189: 12173,
  3996191: 1656,
  3996195: 211,
  3996196: 772,
  3996199: 1063,
  3996203: 40,
  3997425: 3080,
  3997426: 2095,
  3997427: 465,
  3997428: 217}})
```

The `way_id` is the ID that corresponds to OpenStreetMap's *[ways](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Way)*. E.g., for way ID = 3997428 you can get:

[image]

... via https://www.openstreetmap.org/way/3997428. I would like to show a map with Python where all the `way_id`'s can be plotted with a custom color that is based on the `count` column in my data. I know how to plot all the longitude/latitude values via `plotly.express.scatter_mapbox`:

```
fig = px.scatter_mapbox(subsub_traces, lat="latitude", lon="longitude",
                        color="count", zoom=10,
                        mapbox_style='carto-positron',
                        size="count")

plot(fig, auto_open=True)
```

[image]

This obviously plots the geolocations instead of the actual roads. I searched in the documentation of OpenStreetMap for ways (pun intended) to solve this but I could not find the right feature. I also searched in [OSMnx](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)'s docs but to no avail. The only thing I could find that is close is the method `osmnx.plot_graph_route` which colors a route on OSM data, but that is intended for graphs. Any suggestions on how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Try with **folium**: http://python-visualization.github.io/folium/

You need to create a *folium.Map* first, then iterate over your dataframe and plot a **Polyline** for each way.

Note that you need two coordinates for each way, i.e. the start node and end node of the way. Fix your dataframe adding two columns (latitude,longitude) for each point.

Comment: I will try this but the thing is, I only have the way ID's. One way can consist of multiple "nodes" of which I don't have the geolocations.

Comment: The point is that if you have only one coordinate for each way (lat, lng), you will never be able to print the road as a line. You can just print a point on the map, as you did. You can try to get all the nodes of a way as a list and use this list to plot the polyline.

Comment: To get all the nodes of a way you can query OSM APIs by passing your ways IDs. 
Use for example: `https://www.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/way/3996189/full`